# IF ELSE workflow different field but same output

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a sharepoint list form where there are different levels of approvals in the sharepoint designer workflow. However, when the administrator clicks approve or reject in the task, the output which is to sent confirmation email to the users is the same for both approve and reject.

if status equals accepted, inform user through email that it has been approved

else if status equals rejected, inform user through email that it has been rejected

[image]
[image]

may I know what could be the reason for the same output despite putting the correct fields?

Comment: Try to log the value of variable or condition. Through that you might know if the value is reference correctly or some issue in that.

Comment: Please attach snapshot of your workflow, So i can identify if any step is missing.

Comment: Hi I have just updated the attached pictures. Do take a look thank you. @MonicaJagani

Comment: Your lookup box is finding the first item in the associated task lists where `iFast_Approval_2 = Accepted` and returning that. It isn't necessarily finding the task for the item you're trying to get approved. Since it always finds the first one that is accepted, it is always sending the "accepted" email. You need to choose a Field and Value pair that will return a unique task.

Comment: For the field and value pair, does that mean I take a common field from the task list?

Answer (score 0):

Normally a task in SharePoint designer returns an outcome (which button was clicked) and a task ID. If there is an outcome return value, you should use that one. If there isn't one try looking up the task instance using the task ID return value. The return variables are visible at the end of the task action between brackets.